# What are the main differences between AutoLaTeX and LaTeXMk?

Tags: compiling, latexmk

I stumbled upon AutoLaTeX today and it seems to be very similar to LaTeXMk indeed. Can you summarise the main differences, which might help me choose between the two tools?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as it is asking for a compare/contrast, while the linked question is just a big list which currently has few if any details and very specifically does not answer this question.

Comment: The title is perhaps a bit misleading in that respect.

Comment: I have clarified the title.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest answer is to follow the table in the [autolatex site](http://www.arakhne.org/autolatex/). According with that table, Autolatex:

- Is more recent (2014 vs 2012, and in active development, as it can be seen in its git repository)
- Is implemented in python (vs Perl). This is a + for me :-)
- Supports more tex engines (as xelatex, lualatex)
- Can automatically convert some file types to include them in latex documents (images, and some programming languages, to be included as listings, I guess)
- Can export to Elsevier, <s>whatever this means</s> i.e: conform to the document and folder structure in which Elsevier expects the submissions for automatic compilation.
- Has support for some editors, in form of "plugin".

Since I don't really have any experience with this tool (which I just discovered too), I can't go any deeper in the comparison, so I don't deserve nor want the bounty, but I didn't want to leave the question without answer either.

Comment: *Export to Elsevier* is explained below the table.

Comment: It seems to be implemented in Python *and Perl*, approximately half and half. That's a - for me: introducing another dependency.